# Stuart-Maxwell / marginal homogeneity test help in R

Tags: r, matrix, categorical-data, chi-squared

I believe I need to use a Stuart-Maxwell mh test for my data because it is paired (before/after responses) and all categorical. There are 5 possible responses which people answered in a survey. I only have 2 columns (the before/after column and the answer column). There are 388 rows.

Example Data snippet:

```
Response     Action
Before     Option A
Before     Option C
Before     Option D  
Before     Option B
Before     Option E
Before     Option B 
After      Option A
After      Option B
After      Option E
```

I am not very familiar with using categorical data for both variables and am not sure how to convert my data to a matrix in order to use the `StuartMaxwellTest(x)` from the DescTools package or `stuart.maxwell.mh(x)` from the irr package (or any other method of comparing the before and after data for that matter).

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: How can you tell, which before action belongs to which after action?